# How to understand this recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Hello all I am trying to understand this solution to combination sum.

```
 function combinationSum(candidates, target) {
     var result = [];

     if ((candidates == null) || (candidates.length == 0)) {
         return result;
     }

     var cur = [];
     candidates = candidates.sort((a, b) => a - b)
     csh(candidates, target, cur, result, 0);

     return result;
 };

 function csh(cand, target, cur, result, j) {
     //console.log(cur);
     if (target == 0) {
         var temp = cur.slice();
         result.push(temp);
         return;
     }

     for (var i = j; i < cand.length; i++) {
         if (target < cand[i]) {
             return;
         }

         //console.log(cur);
         cur.push(cand[i]);
         console.log(cur);
         csh(cand, target - cand[i], cur, result, i);
         cur.pop();
     }
 }
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/description/

While I understand the basic principles of recursion this problem is a little bit lost on me. So for example for the input:

```
candidates = [2,3,6,7]
target = 7
```

When you first enter the function `cur` is empty so our first iteration is:

```
[],
[2],
[2,2]
```

And then we keep adding `cand[i]` which is currently `2`

```
[2,2,2]
```

However at this point, `target = 1` which is less than `cand[i]` which is `2` so we return. And since we're returning we pop off the stack which pops the last `2` off the stack. Since we've returned we increment `i` and then we add `3` to `cur`

```
[2,2,3]
```

Since our target array is equal to `0` we now return again and my question is, at this point do we keep returning until `cur` is empty and continue the function like the following?

```
[2,2]
[2]
[]
[6]
[]
[7]
```

I'm just trying to understand what is being done in this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target` is local to each invocation of the function. `target` is `0` only for some invocations of the function. Notice that the recursive invocation is:

```
csh(cand, target - cand[i], cur, result, i);
```

The `target` in that scope has not change, but the invocation of `csh` currently being entered will have a lower value for its `target`. When that function returns and the program flow reenters that other level, we resume using the higher value of `target`, insted of the reduce value `target - cand[i]` that was supplied to the subcall.

The algorithm will try all other possibilities on the `[2,2,...]` path as well, before changing the second element to the next alternative. Then it will explore the `[2,3,...]` space, and the `[2,6,...]` space, and ultimately all the `[3,...]`, `[6,...]` and `[7,...]` possibilities as well.

The algorithm always goes as deep as a possible (i.e., as long of an array as possible) when it can do so without going over the original limit.

Note that it does not produce `[2,3,2]`, because an earlier candidate cannot come after a later one (so a `2` can never be subsequent to a `3` in a result). It enforces this by making the `for` look start at `i = j`, where `j` is the array-depth of the last candidate used, so when the result-in-progress ends with the `n`th candidate, it only considers `n`th and higher candidates. this is of practical value because the algorithm only returns one permutation of each value result set: `[2,2,3]` and `[2,3,2]` contain the same set of values.

Comment: Ahh okay I think I know what you mean so it does something like [2] ,[ 2,2] , [2,2,2], pop() now [2,2,3], pop now [2,2,6] then pop now [2,2,7] and then [3],[3,3] .[3,6],[3,7]?

Comment: @motioncity That's basically right except after `[2,2,...]`, it will do all of `[2,3,..]`, `[2,6,...]` and `[2,7,...]` before any `[3,...]`

Answer (score 0):

I completely understand that recursion can be very difficult to understand and to explain as well, but here is my take on it.

1. When csh is called for the 1st time, this is what is being passed

   csh(cand, 7, [], [], 0)
2. Now from the for loop, `i = 0`, function called is

   csh(cand, 5, [2], [], 0)
3. from the loop, `i = 0`, function called is

   csh(cand, 3, [2,2], [], 0)
4. from the loop, `i = 0`, function called is

   csh(cand, 1, [2,2,2],[],0)
5. from the for loop, `target(1) < cand[0](2)`, so return to step Step 4 and pop the last 2 from [2,2,2] resulting in [2,2]
6. from the loop  `i = 1`, function called is

   csh(cand, 0, [2,2,3], [], 1)
7. here, `target == 0` condition is met. so, [2,2,3] is pushed in the result. and then return to step 4. again, 3 is popped from [2,2,3].
8. from the loop i = 2, `target(3) < cand[2](6)`, so return to step 3. and pop 2 from [2,2] resulting in [2].
9. from the loop `i = 1`, function called is

   csh(cand, 2, [2,3], [[2,2,3]], 1)
10. from the loop `i = 1`, `target(2) < cand[1](1)` so return to step 9.

and so no...

Basically, each and every combination will be checked.

```
[2,2,2]
[2,2,3] --> added to result
[2,3,3]
[2,6]
[2,7]
[3,3,3]
[3,6]
[3,7]
[6,6]
[6,7]
[7] --> added to res
```

Comment: I like the explanation! but I think it's supposed to be [2,2,2] for the first call.

Comment: @motioncity : Yes, you are correct, i'll update my explanation